# Printing HTML in Python CGI

Tags: python, html, cgi, printing

I've been teaching myself python and cgi scripting, and I know that your basic script looks like

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi
print "Content-type: text/html"
print 
print "<HTML>"
print  "<BODY>"
print "HELLO WORLD!"
print "</BODY>"
print "</HTML>"
```

My question is, if I have a big HTML file I want to display in python (it had lines and lines of code and sone JS in it) do I have to manually add 'print' in front of each line and turn "s into \" , etc? Or is there a method or script that could convert it for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python supports multiline strings, so you can print out your text in one big blurb.

```
print '''<html>
<head><title>My first Python CGI app</title></head>
<body>
<p>Hello, 'world'!</p>
</body>
</html>'''
```

They support all string operations, including methods (`.upper()`, `.translate()`, etc.) and formatting (`%`), as well as raw mode (`r` prefix) and the `u` unicode prefix.

Comment: So I can copy and paste any HTML like that? Don't I have to add / before each  " ?

Comment: With multiline strings, only the same triple-quote sequence that opened the string can close it.

Comment: Ignacio, you've saved me hours of unnecessary "print" tags and quotes. Thanks!

Comment: you left out the content type

Comment: @bharal: My answer is oriented towards handling the HTML output rather than providing a complete CGI script.

Answer (score 10):

If that big html file is called (for example) `'foo.html'` and lives in the current directory for your CGI script, then all you need as your script's body is:

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
with open('foo.html') as f:
  print f.read()
```

If you're stuck with Python 2.5, add `from __future__ import with_statement` as the start of your module's body.  If you're stuck with an even older Python, change the last two lines into

```
print open('foo.html').read()
```

Note that you don't need to `import cgi` when you're using none of the functionality of the `cgi` module, which is the case both in your example and in this answer.

Comment: So would foo.html have to be in cgi-bin if that's where the script was?

Comment: @Parker: For the example, yes. But you can specify the path when opening the file if it's somewhere else.

Comment: @Parker, yes, exactly in the same directory (for the code I've posted to work; otherwise you have to know, and give, the complete path to the file, not just the name).

Answer (score 0):

When I was first experimenting with decorators, I wrote [this little CGI decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#CGImethodwrapper) to handle the HTML head and body tag boilerplate stuff.  So that you can just write:

```
@CGImethod(title="Hello with Decorator")
def say_hello():
    print '<h1>Hello from CGI-Land</h1>'
```

which when called returns:

```
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Hello with Decorator</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<h1>Hello from CGI-Land</h1>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Then `say_hello` could be called from your HTTP server's `do_GET` or `do_POST` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports multiline string. So you can just copy your HTML code and paste it into the quotations.

```
print ("<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
</html>")
```

and so on!