# Running python script on local server only shows source code

Tags: python

I have a question regarding a Python running problem.
I set up a local server with the Windows command prompt using the `python -m http.server 8000` command, but when I run my script on `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hello.py`, it just shows me the source code instead of actually running the script.

I use the code i found on  [this](http://www.johnloomis.org/python/cgiserver.html) link.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print('Content-Type: text/html')
print()
print('<html>')
print('<head><title>Hello from Python</title></head>')
print('<body>')
print('<h2>Hello from Python</h2>')
print('</body></html>')
```

I've seen several people having the same problem, but I couldn't really find a solution.
I work with Python 3.5

Comment: did you start it with `python -m CGIHTTPServer`? like on the page you linked?

Comment: Follow _all_ of the instructions on that page. Not just some of them. -1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing HTML in Python CGI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169781/printing-html-in-python-cgi)

Comment: When i tried using python -m CGIHTTPServer, it didn't work and i looked in the python docs and found they merged all their server commands it in the `python -m http.server` command. Doesn't it work the same way?

Comment: No. http.server serves the files in the directory and can be useful if you are having static html pages. For executing python apps (or PHP or any other dynamic language which generates html files) you need CGI or some other gateway interfaces. Now as @Daniel suggests you could use --cgi option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler). The command for Python 3 is:

```
python -m http.server --cgi 8000
```